# Reset JavaScript animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

This source code is part of the web page I am studying. I implemented the animation effect. However, I found the problem not to repeat.

The problem is the initial state of the animation. The initialization state was implemented. However, the problem is not solved.

Click inside the `div.main` tag to animate, but it animates only once. Since it is part of the source code, the `if()` statement is entered. Because of this, I want to solve it in a function.

```js
function Reset() {
    var main_Selector = document.querySelector(".main");
    main_Selector.style.animation = 'anim 0.5s ease-in forwards';
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('\
        @keyframes anim {\
                from { background : greenyellow; }\
                to   { background : floralwhite; }\
        }'
    );       
    main_Selector.classList.remove("main");
    void main_Selector.offsetWidth;
    main_Selector.classList.add("main"); 
}
```

```css
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 330px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px dashed mediumpurple;
    background-color:floralwhite;
    animation-direction:alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" onclick="Reset()"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function Reset() {
    var main_Selector = document.querySelector(".main");
    main_Selector.style.animation = '';
    setTimeout(() => { main_Selector.style.animation = 'anim 0.5s ease-in forwards'}, 0);
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('\
        @keyframes anim {\
                from { background : greenyellow; }\
                to   { background : floralwhite; }\
        }'
    );       
    main_Selector.classList.remove("main");
    void main_Selector.offsetWidth;
    main_Selector.classList.add("main"); 
}
```

```css
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 330px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px dashed mediumpurple;
    background-color:floralwhite;
    animation-direction:alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" onclick="Reset()"></div>
```

Comment: Oh My God
Thank you very much.
I studied a lot for 2 days to solve this problem.
However, I haven't solved this problem.
Finally, we decided to ask the 'StackOverflow' community.
I was giving up, but you let me regenerate.
Thank you.

Comment: @donipeter, no worries. btw you could improve the logic. your current logic keeps adding  keyframe ruleset. you could extract that to different method and run only once. Also if you could upvote and accept my answer would be great.

Comment: You also needn't to add and remove `"main"` class.